# How to limit resolutions display in monogame

Tags: monogame, resolution

I can Add resolutions to the list. Here is part of code.

```
List<Vector2> resolutions = new List<Vector2>();
foreach (var item in GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.SupportedDisplayModes)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < item.Width; i++)
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < item.Height; z++)
        {

            resolutions.Add(new Vector2(i,z));
        }
    }
}
```

That is all great and dandy...but i wanna for example remove 320x200 up to 1024x768? Is there is any way to do that and how can i set/see refresh rate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your code is doing what you think it's doing. If I run that code on my computer I get 23,879,696 resolutions in the list.

I think what you intended to write was something more like this:

```
List<Vector2> resolutions = new List<Vector2>();
foreach (var item in GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.SupportedDisplayModes)
{
    resolutions.Add(new Vector2(item.Width, item.Height));
}
```

Which will produce the following output:

```
{X:320 Y:200}
{X:320 Y:240}
{X:400 Y:300}
{X:512 Y:384}
{X:640 Y:400}
{X:640 Y:480}
{X:800 Y:600}
{X:1024 Y:768}
{X:1152 Y:864}
{X:1280 Y:600}
{X:1280 Y:720}
{X:1280 Y:768}
{X:1280 Y:800}
{X:1280 Y:960}
{X:1280 Y:1024}
{X:1360 Y:768}
{X:1366 Y:768}
{X:1400 Y:1050}
{X:1440 Y:900}
{X:1600 Y:900}
{X:1600 Y:1200}
{X:1680 Y:1050}
{X:1920 Y:1080}
{X:1920 Y:1200}
```

You could also use LINQ to produce the same list.

```
var resolutions = GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.SupportedDisplayModes
    .Select(item => new Vector2(item.Width, item.Height))
    .ToList();
```

Now to get to you're actual questions.

> but i wanna for example remove 320x200 up to 1024x768?

To remove the resolutions you don't want you're going to have to create some custom logic. I'm not sure exactly what you want but you could do something fairly simple, like filter out resolutions with a width less than 1024.

```
var resolutions = GraphicsAdapter.DefaultAdapter.SupportedDisplayModes
    .Where(r => r.Width >= 1024)
    .Select(item => new Vector2(item.Width, item.Height))
    .ToList();
```

Or of course, you could get more clever and somehow include `Height` or `AspectRatio` in the filter. That parts really up to you.

> how can i set/see refresh rate?

The refresh rate is an entirely different question. By default MonoGame / XNA refresh at a fixed 60fps so you may want to turn that off.

```
IsFixedTimeStep = false;
```

Or alternately you can change the refresh rate from the default 60fps.

```
TargetElapsedTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0f / 100.0f);
```

One last thing you should know is that the frame rate might be limited by VSync. This means the game's refresh rate will be limited by the refresh rate of your monitor. To turn that off set `SynchronizeWithVerticalRetrace` on the graphics device manager.

```
_graphicsDeviceManager = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this) 
{
    SynchronizeWithVerticalRetrace = false
};
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for explaining! Should i post a new question or in here as addon?

Comment: Stack overflow works best if questions are kept separate. If you have a new question, don't add it here. It can take some practice to [ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) but you'll find you get much better answers if you do.